# Example.txt file not getting updated if test is failed in before(:all) in Rspec

Tags: ruby, automation, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

Im facing an issue currently, I have my test suite written Rspec. Lets say the spec get failed in before(:all) itself, then the example.txt file is not getting updated with the failed cases. Can you help on this ?

Comment: What does your test look like, and what does example.txt look like after the failed run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a exit present in after(:all) method in my code that is the reason example.txt was not getting updated